# iOS Swift, Find minimum amount from JSON array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable tableData which contains JSON data. I want to extract the minimum value ("amount") from this JSON.

So from the data, I am trying to get something like

```
amountArray = [28.8, 52, 10.4, 9.35, 8.32]
```

from which, I can extract the minimum value like

```
let minimumAmount = minElement(amountArray)
```

My JSON data is as below:
var tableDate = [ ]

// which contains:

```
(
    {
    amount = "20.8";
    companyName = valentino;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 1 ";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "52";
    companyName = james;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 2";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            1,
            0,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "10.4";
    companyName = nikki;
    optionalNoteText = “This is test 3”;
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "9.35";
    companyName = jason;
    optionalNoteText = “Test is test 4;
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            1,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "8.32";
    companyName = vicky;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 5";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            1,
            1,
            0,
            0
        )
    );
}
```

)

Comment: Do you want to get the minimum value from the small array of numbers? Or from the big JSON?

Comment: `minElement(map(amountArray, { $0.["amount"] }))`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I want to extract minimum value directly form the tableData. I don't really have the amountArray (this was just for explanation). I just have the JSON data tableData from which I need the minimum value of "amount". I replaced amountArray with tableData as showed by "agy" member below, but I am getting the same error:  Expected member name following '.'. Do you know whats going on?

Comment: @Riding.Driving I've made a typo and you blindly copied the example instead of paying attention. Obviously there's no need for a dot, that should be `$0["amount"]`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Works after making following changes:          let amountArray = map(tableData, { $0["amount"]!!})
                        println("\(amountArray)")
                        let minimumAmount = minElement(amountArray as! [Double])
                        println("\(minimumAmount)")  Do you think its a good practice to unwrap (!!) twice?

Comment: @Riding.Driving It's certainly ugly, but if you've got two levels of optionals, that's you have to do. I'm no Swift programmer though! Maybe someone else could suggest a way in which it can be done more nicely.